# Получить id после добавления записи

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в БД id auto_increment, можно ли получить его после INSERT?

Comment: [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php)

 [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$id = mysqli->insert_id();
функция возвращает id последней добавленной записи.